# ViewController's outlet view first non-nil, then nil when loading from bundle

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, bundle, iboutlet

I am loading a `UIViewController` from a bundle with `initWithNibName:bundle:`. If I set a breakpoint in its `viewDidLoad` I can see that its `view` is set. I can also see this when viewing `About.xib` in the Interface Builder.

However once the view is actually used for the first time (in a call to `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]` according to my app's logic) I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "About" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

This is the call that also triggers `viewDidLoad`. So apparently during the call, `view` is first non-nil (as it should be) and later apparently becomes nil again.

If I alternatively type `po [viewController view]` in the debugger immediately prior to the call I get this error (which is presumably just another presentation of the same symptom):

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception
>   breakpoint(-3).. The process has been returned to the state before
>   expression evaluation.

How can I load and use the view controller in conjunction with an existing navigation bar without running into these errors?

**UPDATE** The problem apparently disappears if I load the view controller from my a storyboard (not necessarily my main storyboard) instead of from a XIB file.

Answer (score 3):

When viewing the xib file in Xcode, in the identity inspector, is the custom subclass set to you view controller's class? If you set that, then go to the connections inspector, you will see an attribute called "view", just drag that to your view in Interface builder and it should work

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by stating that it's `view` is set also when viewing the view controller in the Interface Builder. Problem remains though.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you were overriding some default `UIViewController` behavior, either make its `view` a `weak` property, a strange `loadView` method or just not calling `super` in one of your overridden methods.

---

Another common error is calling a non-matching `super` method (call `super viewDidLoad` from an `awakeFromNib`, etc.) which could happen when you move code around or after trying different things.

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past caused by not calling `[super loadView]`.