# Debugger say something wrong with outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

My Problem: When I build and run my program in the simulator it instantly crashes.

Debugger says:

> "Thread 1: internal ObjC exception breakpoint (-3)

Code Problem: "@IBOutlet weak var Record_Minutes: UIButton!"

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate,  
AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var TextField_Mintues: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Record_Mintues: UIButton! 
@IBOutlet weak var Record_Unlimited2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
```

Comment: Can you ensure this outlet is properly connected in IB?

Comment: check below link hope it will help you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917607/viewcontrollers-outlet-view-first-non-nil-then-nil-when-loading-from-bundle

Comment: yes i can confirm it is an outlet